# How do I make a toast display for this specific edit text field

Tags: android

Hi I am kind of stuck here, I have an activity which lets the user create a transaction from his bank account, the activity has some text fields.One of the text field is for balance entry. When the user enters the balance he wants to withdraw there should be an internal checking of the balance present already in the user's account. I know how to create the internal checking, the problem is that when the user enters an amount in that particular text field there should be a toast displayed letting the user know that he has entered an invalid balance withdraw request,or something like that. How can I do this? Are there any listeners for accessing that particular text field?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of showing a toast message, you should use [TextView.seterror](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) . This can be done where you are doing checking.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Just add the Textwatcher as a listener on your editable:

```
editable.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //Override Methods
});
```

In the method `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` you can start your validation. If validation fails you can inform the user with a Toast or an error text(setError) on the Editable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a validation error on a specific EditText you should use:
{EditText}.setError(CharSequence error)
OR
{EditText}.setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon)

That should bring up the toast you want.

Regarding the logic of validation, it's up to you of course...